# List initialization of function template arguments with automatic template type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-argument-deduction, list-initialization

Here's the setup to illustrate the problem.

```
template <typename T>
struct opt {
  const char* name;
  T x;

  template <typename X>
  opt(const char* name, X&& x)
  : name(name), x(std::forward<X>(x)) { }
};

template <typename T>
opt(const char*, T&&) -> opt< some_type_transformation<T> >;

template <typename... T>
void function(opt<T>&&... opts) {
  // do something with the passed arguments
}
```

With this, the following syntax can be used.

```
function(opt("a",1),opt("b",2.),opt("c",3u));
```

But the following does not work.

```
function({"a",1},{"b",2.},{"c",3u});
```

Theoretically, there is enough information to figure out what to do in the second case, since the `function` takes arguments only of type `opt<T>`, and `T` can be deduced using the defined deduction guide.

Can something be done to enable the second, terser syntax?

Comment: `opt` is not an aggregate; it has a constructor (though I'm not sure why). But even if it were an aggregate, this wouldn't work.

Comment: Maybe I don't have the terminology straight. I was referring to the use of `{ }` without explicitly naming the type as "aggregate initialization", not to `opt` as an "aggregate". `opt` has a constructor because this is an example. In reality, the constructor may do something non-trivial.

Comment: If "aggregate initialization" only refers to the initialization of aggregates, then my bad. Don't read into the implementation details too much. All I'm trying to do is pass ordered sets of arguments to a function, and have a type deduced from one of the elements of the set.

Comment: "*I was referring to the use of { } without explicitly naming the type as "aggregate initialization"*" That's just [list initialization (specifically copy-list-initialization)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), which may invoke aggregate initialization depending on the type.

Comment: *"there is enough information to figure out what to do in the second case"* - If you never include any other header with a function (template) that accepts 3 "things". Then it's no longer quite enough information. Not to mention there's also ADL to consider at times. And ultimately, the standard has a motive of being against changing behavior when new declarations pop up in most unrelated scopes. Failing in the "obvious" case is about consistent behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Template argument deduction relies on using the type of an expression to match a pattern defined in a template parameter.

Copy-list-initialization (list-initialization where the name of the type being used is not immediately available where the braced-init-list is used) is a process where a sequence of values is matched against the declaration of a named type to figure out which initialization form to use. That is, it involves some degree of deduction.

What you're trying to do effectively involves *double* deduction, since a braced-init-list by itself doesn't have a well-defined type. You would need to use the pattern from the template parameter to match some set of possible types and their constructors against the braced-init-list's members.

Such a thing would be theoretically possible in some cases of template argument deduction, but spelling out exactly what those cases are is exceedingly difficult, as the way template argument deduction works is itself pretty complex. As such, the standard takes the easy way out and just forbids it entirely: you cannot use copy-list-initialization on a parameter involved in template argument deduction, period.

So there's no shorter form out there. You're just going to have to spell it out.